# How do I use a subscriber callback to change a global variable?

Tags: ros, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use a callback for the current location to update a global variable I have that's just a tuple. However, the callback is working fine, but the global variable is never updated.

I normally use a callback as a loop to run whatever it is I want to do, but in this case I have a separate loop choosing locations to navigate too. I want this loop to gain access to the current location.

Also, I'm not sure I understand exactly how callbacks work, and this may be me problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38766/how-do-i-use-a-subscriber-callback-to-change-a-global-variable?/) by [IFLORbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1978/iflorbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2012-07-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-07-13**:
[edit: should have been an answer, not a comment.]

**Comment by [IFLORbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1978/iflorbot/) on 2012-07-16**:
Ok cool. I'm also new to Python, so that could explain my problem as well. Thanks.

**Comment by [IFLORbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1978/iflorbot/) on 2012-07-16**:
Also, while we're here, is there a good thread/site for understanding callbacks? I think I get them now, but it took me a while as it was new and at first seemed like magic....

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-07-17**:
@IFORbot: sounds to me like you should start a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're in python, take a look at the "global" keyword. If you're in C++, we're going to need a code snippet.

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2012-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2